# Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'

Tags: ssrs-2008, reportingservices-2005, reporting-services

I have few SSRS 2008 reports. Databases are CRM databases. I have created a group of 10 users. Each user has different permissions(user can see data of only those databases which he has access from CRM side security).

When user tried to see reports from his place(machine) every time he gets this error.

**An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
   Cannot create a connection to data source 'DB_NAME'. (rsErrorOpeningConnection)
      Cannot open database "CRM_Database" requested by the login. The login failed. Login            failed for user 'NTAUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.**

I am using windows authentication. within the server reports are working fine. Outside the server we are getting this error.i got few suggestions that its a double hop issue.Solutions can be :

1. **Use stored credential**. (In my case I can't use because every user has access to different database. He can select database in reports whatever he has access to and he will get data only for that database.)
2. **Kerberos setting**.( I don't know how to do that when you have Windows 7 and SQL 2008 R2)

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

"NTAUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON" is the built in IIS account on your report server. The reports are being executed from this account which serves up the page to the user.

Update your Data Source to use "Connect using: Credentials supplied by the user running the report" and checking "Use as Windows credentials" (Kerberos), if their AD account is setup with the appropriate DB permissions on the SQL Server. when connecting to the Data Source. Windows integrated security works also if you are on the domain.

Since you need to pass the user's account to the DB for authentication using credentials stored securely on server (Stored Credential) will not work for the scenario you describe as every user will hit the database with the same credentials.